# WhatsApp status in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, whatsapp, status

When I had the Target API 29, the app was showing WhatsApp statuses, but when I increase the target api to 32, it is not showing the statuses.

```
public File getWhatsupFolder() {
        if (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp" + File.separator + "Media" + File.separator + ".Statuses").isDirectory()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp" + File.separator + "Media" + File.separator + ".Statuses");
        } else {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "WhatsApp" + File.separator + "Media" + File.separator + ".Statuses");
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of my getting status that was working fine in target api 29.

If anyone knows what is the issue. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You no longer have access to app-specific storage of other apps.

Comment: As @CommonsWare said, in the API 32, you don't have permission to access the WhatsApp app folders, you have permission to access only your created folders, you need to use scoped storage instead of the old storage

Comment: Can you please send me the code for getting Scoped storage, or the code for achieving this? Please.